# How to correctly use parameters passed to an android thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, inputstream

I have an external .hash file which I tired reading as a simple remote text file:

```
private class getHash extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String str = null;
        try {
            // Create a URL for the desired page
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);

            // Read all the text returned by the server
            InputStream is =  url.openStream();//The line it crashes on
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
            str = in.readLine();
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        hash = result;
    }
}
```

Then I call the thread :

```
getHash hashThread =  new getHash();
hashThread.execute(new String[]{"http://www......................hash"});
```

During execution of the noted line in the class all stops are pulled and I get slapped by the classy `Source not found` crash.

LogCat gives this error:

```
W/dalvikvm(724): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
```

Comment: Please post logcat error output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this in debug mode or regular mode?
The `source not found` message would seem to indicate you are trying to step into code that has no source attached for it.

Also have you added 
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
to your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Thank you for response but I did add the necessary permissions.

Comment: What about the first part?  Are you running in debug or regular mode?

Comment: There are two different ways to run an Android application (at least assuming you are using Eclipse).  The first is regular/release which has a green play arrow on the top bar or you can right click on your project and click Run As -> Android Application.  The other is debug which has a little purple bug symbol on the top bar.  If you are running in debug mode it will attempt to step through the code, and if the source code for Android is not attached (it is not if you only have the SDK installed), then you will get that `Source not found` error

Comment: There is no relevance whats so ever how IDE is arranged. So I do it both ways.